# Added user to CentOS, Updated sshd_config with AllowUsers, Login denied

Tags: linux, ssh, centos

CentOS 5.3.  I can SSH into the system as root just fine.  Added a user and set their password.  They have shell access (/bin/bash).  I can su to the account from root just fine.  I updated /etc/ssh/sshd_config with:

AllowUsers myNewUser

And restarted sshd: /etc/init.d/sshd restart

When trying to ssh into the server with the new user, I get a permission denied.  And yes, I've double and triple checked that I am using the correct password.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you turn on verbose logging you'll probably be able to tell quite quickly what the problem is.

Comment: look at /var/log/secure and /var/log/messages for ways to debug and post that info here

Comment: su <newuser> is different from su - <newuser>.  Did you try the latter, which starts a login shell?

Answer (score 2):

Can you change the Log level in your sshd_config to look like this:

```
LogLevel DEBUG
```

Restart SSH. Then try logging in as myNewUser and post the output from /var/log/secure here (after stripping out any specific identifying information!) <sup>1</sup>

1: The DEBUG log level can violate User privacy according to [the man-page for sshd(5)](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sshd_config+5)

Answer (score 1):

Is the uid >= 500? On RHEL/CentOS, the default PAM config has a check for uid. Another possibility could be the password is expired (if you set it as root using `passwd <username>`) - does a login rather than su to the user reveal any issues there? Does it work using Pubkey authentication rather than a password?

The reason is probably logged in authlog, and troubleshooting without that log data is really just speculation.